# glTexImage3D - Invalid Operation

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I tried to use `glTexImage3D`in my android application and it throws an `W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glTexImage3DOES:665>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error.
My line is the following:

```
GLES30.glTexImage3D(GLES30.GL_TEXTURE_3D, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA, sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ, 0, GLES30.GL_RGBA, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, data);
```

where `data` is an `IntBuffer` with the capacity of `4*sizeX*sizeY*sizeZ`. The data inside are from a binary file which I read via `InputStream` and then parsed to `int`. The [documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexImage3D.xml) didn't help me much so I hope you guys can.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I just used a `ByteBuffer`instead of an `IntBuffer` and changed the type to `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`.